# change write permission if curl returns write error in windows

Tags: php, windows, curl, command-line-interface, php-curl

Whenever I run this code `shell_exec("curl -o/$filepath https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/logs/php_memcache-3.0.8-$php_version-$thread_type-$vc-$bit-logs.zip | df -k . | tr -dc '[:print:]'");`  in

> php,

it always return `tr: write error`.

How can I grant

> write

access for the

> script

from the commandline?

N.B: I want to programmically grant access for the script if user does not have access to write to the script

Edit: the error return body also includes this
`curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16094)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can embed `windows powershell` inside `shell_exec()` function like this

```
shell_exec("powershell -command \"& { Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/logs/php_memcache-3.0.8-$php_version-$thread_type-$vc-$bit-logs.zip -Destination dir/to/save/to/with/name }\"");
```

Comment: lemme try it out

Comment: it works but if use inside the IF statement, doesn't run the codes in the IF block

Comment: Try putting it inside the TRY and CATCH statement